# How to create dynamic array fo array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I am reading data and loading in two dimensional array using following code by initializing 2d array (series)

where series is structure like as follows (highchart series)

series: [{
       name: ''
       data: []
    }]

**Manual code:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>


  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

  <style type='text/css'>

  </style>




<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {

 var options = {
        chart :{
                  type: 'polygon',
                  renderTo: 'container',

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Height vs Weight'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: false,
            gridLineWidth:0,
            lineWidth:0,
            labels:{
                enabled: false
            }
        },
          series: [{},{}]
    };

    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        options.series[0].data = data[0];
        options.series[1].data = data[1];

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    })

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


</body>
```

But i want to initialize dynamic array so that i can insert arrays(data[i]) dynamically.

**data.json**

```
[
    [
        [
            153,
            42
        ],
        [
            149,
            46
        ],
        [
            149,
            55
        ],
        [
            152,
            60
        ]
    ],
    [
        [
            253,
            142
        ],
        [
            349,
            146
        ],
        [
            349,
            155
        ],
        [
            352,
            160
        ]
    ]
]
```

**dynamic code:**

```
series: [[]]

 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        for (i=0; i<data.length(); i++) {
           series[i].data = data[i];
         }
    })
```

above code does not seem to be working. Pls help me how can i solve my problem.

Comment: edited my answer with the data structure you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) function to append dynamically

**EDIT** with second array to get the required "data" structure

```
// initialize array
var series = [];


$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    var temparray = [];
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        temparray["data"] = data[i];
        series.push(temparray);
    }
})
```

Comment: And, `.length` is a property!

Comment: Thanks, missed that one.

Comment: just use this: `series.push({ name : "", data : data[i] });`